# How can I get UIViewController to properly refresh / update its view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` with a label that gets its text set from an external server. In `viewDidLoad` I add:

```
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

After a few minutes the server updates the text, and in the app I press a button that activates this:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

but the text of the label doesn't get updated until I recompile the app. How can I get the subview label to refresh/get the new text from the server?

Comment: When finish the api call to the server (Actually when you got the text from the API call). Then you have the text with you right? So plz set the text on the label using `setText:` method of `UILabel`.

Comment: I need the text to update everytime the button is pressed, where do I add setText?

Comment: If you are setting the text from the API response then you have to make a call to the api every time you press the button right?

Comment: So at the time the api call completes, you can call a selector on main thread to update the label with the latest text you got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

How about `label.text = @"new title";` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add setText inside the Buttons event.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
 [self.view addSubview:button];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) buttonPressMethod:(id) sender
{
   label.text = @"The updated text from the server";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(void)viewwillAppear
{
  NSTIMER * chat = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40 target:self selector:@selector(getdata) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  // method will call for every 40 sec

}

-(void)getdata
{
    call the data from sever and replace data in label
}